# How can I test which API performs better for my NODE.js project?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, testing, serverside-javascript

Question:
We have a project in University where we have to implement a server-sided application and use a RESTful API in Node.js. We want to call the functions provided by the API to get information like direction , route, facilities within a radius. So, we have two first options: Google APIs and Here APIs.
How can I tell which one suits the needs of our project more and which is overall "better" (f.e. how fast you get a response)? Or what other parameters should be included when making such a decision in this situation?

Thank you for your answers and advices!

Comment: > Or what other parameters should be included when making such a decision in this situation?

This probably depends on what you intend to use the APIs for. If you make a lot of requests, then of course speed is a factor (although I would suppose that they are more or less the same in this regard).

In any other case, there might be factors like pricing, accuracy, data structure, features (IIRC HERE supports directions for trucks, Maps does not) etc. you might want to consider

Comment: @Jb31 Good comment! Since it's "just" a Uni project, data structure and features are those (more important) parameters I should include in the process of decision making. Thanks!